# How to make this 3 x 3 grid of icons and text stack properly with correct margins?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have set up this section of the website with 3x3 grid using bootstrap and css to draw graphics:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="expbox">
        <div class="icircle cl-effect-12 hvr-bounce-out">
          <div class="icon">
            <span class="rt-snowmobile rt-icon"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="headings">
          <h3>Snowmobile Safaris</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="iconboxborder"> </div>
        <div class="infoboxtext">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores provident temporibus porro adipisci, voluptates est, accusamus omnis unde velit aspernatur</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="expbox">
        <div class="icircle cl-effect-12 hvr-bounce-out">
          <div class="icon">
            <span class="rt-crosscountry-skiing rt-icon"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="headings">
          <h3>Cross-country Skiing</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="iconboxborder"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="expbox">
        <div class="icircle cl-effect-12 hvr-bounce-out">
          <div class="icon">
            <span class="rt-downhill-skiing rt-icon"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="headings">
          <h3>Downhill Skiing</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="iconboxborder"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="expbox">
        <div class="icircle cl-effect-12 hvr-bounce-out">
          <div class="icon">
            <span class="rt-river-rafting rt-icon"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="headings">
          <h3>River Rafting</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="iconboxborder"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="expbox">
        <div class="icircle cl-effect-12 hvr-bounce-out">
          <div class="icon">
            <span class="rt-hiking rt-icon"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="headings">
          <h3>Hiking</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="iconboxborder"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="expbox">
        <div class="icircle cl-effect-12 hvr-bounce-out">
          <div class="icon">
            <span class="rt-safaris rt-icon"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="headings">
          <h3>Animal Safaris</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="iconboxborder"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And CSS

```
.expbox {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  width: 330px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  margin: 35px;
  z-index: 0;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.icircle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 105px;
  height: 105px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 10px solid #DB2B39;
  border-radius: 100%;
  left: -30px;
  top: -30px;
}

.icon {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 54px;
  left: 15px;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 999;
}

.icon:hover .rt-icon:before {
  content: '\25BA';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 5px;
}

.iconboxborder {
  position: absolute;
  background: #DB2B39;
  width: 70%;
  height: 3px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.infoboxtext {
    position: absolute;
    left: 82px;
    top: 35px;
    width: 50%;
}
.headings {
    position: absolute;
    top: -30px;
    left: 80px;
}
```

Please take a look at this codepen http://codepen.io/ex1tium/pen/QEYazp

As you can see when resizing the window, 3 columns are stacking on top of each other at 900px width and not pushing the 3rd item on a row downwards. Ideally I'd like to have 3 activity boxes side by side on big screen, 2 boxes on tablet resolutions and on extra small screen only 1 box per row.

The graphics also stack on top of each other, I tried setting margins/paddings with no luck. [look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGpbZ.png)

The circle has to have static width and height because it will deform otherwise on resize.

Please help me restructure this code or atleast point me in a right direction.

I know it must have something to do with absolute/relative positioning on graphic elements but I just can't seem to be able to wrap it in a container properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have different layouts on different screens, you may want to utilise Bootstraps `col-*` class.  Here is an example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YWBZGX

The changes are:

1. Replaced all `col-sm-4` with `col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12` to use Bootstrap's 12 columns layout.  So on Medium screens each block is taking 4 columns (so a rows show 12/4=3 blocks), and on Small ones it takes 6 (so a row shows 12/6=2), and on Extra small ones it shows 1 per row.
2. Removing the `row` and `container` so the last one of the first three and the first one of the last three can be contained in the same row.  The classes `row` and `container` will force them to be grouped into different.. containers?

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Change all `col-sm-4` to `col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-4`